# How to access an entity properties original value?

Tags: php, cakephp, entity, cakephp-3.0

```
debug($attachment);

object(App\Model\Entity\Attachment) {

    'id' => (int) 73,
    'apartment_id' => (int) 1,
    'name' => 'bla bla bla',
    'caption' => 'bla bla',
    'position' => (int) 1,
    '_locale' => 'eng',
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [
        'caption' => 'original caption'
    ],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Attachments'

}
echo $attachment->caption; # bla bla
```

**How to access and print a part of this array?**

```
'[original]' => [
            'caption' => 'original caption'
        ],
echo $attachment-> ???
```

Comment: The same way you'd access any other array key

Comment: The above given output is an `object` and not `array`

Comment: @Uchiha you're right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dumping objects doesn't necessarily give you an actual representation of the objects structure, but custom formatted debug information, defined via [**the magic `__debugInfo()` method**](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo).

Properties enclosed in brackets are special debug info, what is being shown there might have been gathered from anywhere but a property with the same name.

I would suggest that you read the docs and have a look at the source, there you can find the `EntityTrait::getOriginal()` method, which lets you read values from the protected `EntityTrait::$_original` property, which is where the special `[original]` debug info property gets its data from.

```
echo $attachment->getOriginal('caption');
```

See

- **[API > \Cake\Datasource\EntityTrait::getOriginal()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityTrait.html#_getOriginal)**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.13/src/Datasource/EntityTrait.php#L879**